# Consumer contains the previous value instead of new value

Tags: flutter

I have a parent widget, which contains a checklist. When the checklist is updated, it should update a provider, where I then have a consumer in the parent widget. For some reason though, the values in the consumer seem to be the "old" value rather than the new one. I have checked it is the exact same instance of the object. Even when debugging, it hits the update and notify part first, and then the consumer after, yet the consumer value is still the old value.

The explanation is probably terrible so here's the code snippets:

The consumer:

```
return Consumer<Settings>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Settings settings, Widget child) {
      log.d("Build dialog ${settings.activeConditions().getIds().length}");
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: const Text("My Title"),
          children: <Widget>[
            ChooseChecklist(),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

The checklist on changed function:

```
 onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  checkboxData[i].isChecked = value;
                  settings.setActiveConditions(ActiveConditions(ids: getChecked()));
                });
              },
```

And the settings function:

```
  void setActiveConditions(ActiveConditions newValue) {
    _activeConditions = newValue;
    log.d(
        "Active conditions set and notify listeners now ${_activeConditions.getIds().length}");
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

On first load where I have 0 ids, the logs are:

- Rebuild dialog 0

Then when I select 1 checkbox (so 1 in total are selected), the logs are:

- Active conditions set and notify listeners now 1
- Rebuild dialog 0

So we can see that the "1" is correct, but the "0" in the rebuild dialog is not. And then when I deselect that checkbox (so 0 in total are selected), the logs are:

- Active conditions set and notify listeners now 0
- Rebuild dialog 1

I am honestly at a loss as to why the rebuild dialog is accessing some previous values that shouldn't exist anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the whole code ?

Comment: Figured it out, thanks for looking. I basically had another piece of code that was updating the settings, but didn't realise that could be being called.